# Combining and Transforming Data Frames in R

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, data-processing

I have a bunch of data frames that look like this in R:

```
print(output[2])
Button Intensity Acc Intensity RT    Time tdelta SubjectID CoupleID PrePost
 1:      0        30   0       0.0  0 83325.87  0.000      1531 153    Post
 2:      1        30   1      13.5  0 83362.65 36.782      1531 153    Post
 3:      1        30   1      15.0  0 83376.68 14.027      1531 153    Post
 4:      1        30   1       6.0  0 83392.27 15.585      1531 153    Post
 5:      1        30   1      15.0  0 83398.77  6.507      1531 153    Post

 print(output[1])
 [[1]]
     Button Intensity Acc Intensity RT     Time tdelta SubjectID CoupleID PrePost
  1:      0        30   0       0.0  0 77987.93  0.000      1531 153 Pre
  2:      1        30   1      13.5  0 78084.57 96.639      1531 153 Pre
  3:      1        30   1      15.0  0 78098.62 14.054      1531 153 Pre
  4:      1        30   1       6.0  0 78114.13 15.508      1531 153 Pre
  5:      1        30   1      15.0  0 78120.67  6.537      1531 153 Pre
```

I want to combine them into one big data frame that has the following logic and format:

```
SubjectID  CoupleID  PrePost  Miss1RT   Miss2RT Miss3RT Hit1RT   Hit2RT  Hit3RT
1531    153          Post     0.00       NA     NA      NA     36.78    14.027
1531    153          Pre      0.00       NA     NA      NA     96.638   14.054
```

if Button == 0, then it's a Miss, if it ==1, then it's a Hit. So, it should be something like:

```
for row in output[i].rows:
   if Button ==0:
      Miss1RT ==tdelta
   elif Button ==1;
      Miss1RT =='NA'
```

and then a flipped version where if Button is 1, Hit[i]RT is tdelta or else 'NA'.

There are 26 lines per data frame and each row is either a hit or a miss so there will be 26 Miss and 26 Hit columns and each SubjectID gets two rows - one for Pre and one for Post. So the column headers for the final output will be:

```
SubjectID  CoupleID  PrePost  Miss1RT   Miss2RT ...Miss26RT  Hit1RT  Hit2RT ... Hit26RT
```

I'm new to R and struggling with the proper syntax.

Comment: Do you only want to look at the first two `Hits` and `Misses`? Or do you want to look at all possible? I.e. would you want a `Hit2RT = 15.585` for your `Post`, `CoupleID = 153`?

Comment: I want Hit1-26RT and the same for Miss1-26RT for each Pre/Post SubjectID so that each of the 26 Button==1 or 0 row creates a number in either Hit[i]RT or Miss[i]RT and a 'NA' in the other. Edited the post for clarity.

Comment: So should `Hit1RT` be `NA`? and then `Hit2RT` be `36.78`?

Comment: *facepalm* yes. Let me fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
#Get data in structure OP has
output <- list(pre, post)
output2 <- lapply(output, function(x) cbind(x, num = paste0(1:nrow(x), "RT")))
pre_post <- do.call("rbind", output2)

#Perform actual calculations
pre_post$miss <- ifelse(pre_post$Button == 0, pre_post$tdelta, NA)
pre_post$hit <- ifelse(pre_post$Button == 1, pre_post$tdelta, NA)

pre_post_melted <- melt(pre_post, id.vars = c("SubjectID", "CoupleID", "num", "PrePost"), measure.vars = c("hit","miss"))
pre_post_res <- dcast(pre_post_melted, SubjectID + CoupleID + PrePost ~ variable + num, sep = "")

pre_post_res

  #SubjectID CoupleID PrePost hit_1RT hit_2RT hit_3RT hit_4RT hit_5RT miss_1RT miss_2RT miss_3RT miss_4RT miss_5RT
#1      1531      153    Post      NA  36.782  14.027  15.585   6.507        0       NA       NA       NA       NA
#2      1531      153     Pre      NA  96.639  14.054  15.508   6.537        0       NA       NA       NA       NA
```

We transpose the data to dynamically create all the variables we want. We also stack the data to avoid repeated steps.

---

**Data:**

```
pre <- structure(list(Button = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Intensity = c(30L, 
30L, 30L, 30L, 30L), Acc = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Intensity = c(0, 
13.5, 15, 6, 15), RT = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Time = c(77987.93, 
78084.57, 78098.62, 78114.13, 78120.67), tdelta = c(0, 96.639, 
14.054, 15.508, 6.537), SubjectID = c(1531L, 1531L, 1531L, 1531L, 
1531L), CoupleID = c(153L, 153L, 153L, 153L, 153L), PrePost = c("Pre", 
"Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Pre")), .Names = c("Button", "Intensity", 
"Acc", "Intensity", "RT", "Time", "tdelta", "SubjectID", "CoupleID", 
"PrePost"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

post <- structure(list(Button = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Intensity = c(30L, 
30L, 30L, 30L, 30L), Acc = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Intensity = c(0, 
13.5, 15, 6, 15), RT = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Time = c(83325.87, 
83362.65, 83376.68, 83392.27, 83398.77), tdelta = c(0, 36.782, 
14.027, 15.585, 6.507), SubjectID = c(1531L, 1531L, 1531L, 1531L, 
1531L), CoupleID = c(153L, 153L, 153L, 153L, 153L), PrePost = c("Post", 
"Post", "Post", "Post", "Post")), .Names = c("Button", "Intensity", 
"Acc", "Intensity", "RT", "Time", "tdelta", "SubjectID", "CoupleID", 
"PrePost"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It looks like the first step is to combine a "pre" and a "post" list of data frames but they are all just in one list of data frames, "output".  

When I tried 


`output$miss <- ifelse(output$Button == 0, output$tdelta, NA)
output$hit <- ifelse(output$Button == 1, output$tdelta, NA)`

it didn't give me any errors but didn't seem to change anything. 


`pre_post_melted <- melt(output, id.vars = c("SubjectID", "CoupleID", "num", "PrePost"), measure.vars = c("hit","miss"))
Error in melt.data.table(X[[i]], ...) : 
  One or more values in 'id.vars' is invalid.`

Comment: @HeatherCohen That's because it sounds like `output` is a list. Try stacking `output$pre` and `output$post`

Comment: Or in your case stack `output[[1]]` and `output[[2]]`

Comment: Since there are 13 data frames in the list `output` and may be more in the future, I changed it to: `df <- do.call("rbind", output)

df$miss <- ifelse(df$Button == 0, df$tdelta, NA)
df$hit <- ifelse(df$Button == 1, df$tdelta, NA)`

After the `melted` line, I get this error `Error in melt.data.table(df, id.vars = c("SubjectID", "CoupleID", "num",  : 
  One or more values in 'id.vars' is invalid.`

Comment: That's because you need the `num` column. You can create it on each of your data frames in your lists with `lapply(output, function(x) cbind(x, num = paste0(1:nrow(x), "RT")))`